# c++ Linux input from console (inside docker container)

Tags: c++, linux, docker

I'm trying to do something which seems very basic, to get user input with c++ in a linux console.
However just using:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int amount;
    
    std::cout << "Input your number: ";
    std::cin >> amount;
}
```

It just skips the cin, i tried flushing the stream, but it doesnt matter.
I have been looking for an answer for 2 days. But other people seem to be able to do it this way just fine.

The difference might be that I run it inside a docker container?

Comment: Perhaps `stdin` is closed. Are you running it in interactive mode (`-it`) in your container?

Comment: Are you using the `-a` option when running the container?

I think that should help, [here's](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options) the docs for docker options

Comment: I tried both, at the same time, and each alone. Both dont work. It keeps skipping the cin specifically. No errors or warnings even.

Comment: You could check for `eof` just to verify that `stdin` is closed. `std::cout << std:.cin.eof() << '\n';`

Comment: What if you start `bash` in the contaner (`... -it container /bin/bash`) - does that work?

Comment: You are awesome, your last suggestion worked :)